# Forecast usage at end of the month given the current usage

Tags: java, android, time

I've check out [ChronoUnit and Period classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html), but they seems no use since Android does not support Java-8's time package.

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 Date currentDate = calendar.getTime();

 // Set to first day of month
 calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
 Date firstDayOfMonth = calendar.getTime();
```

I know I could get the answer by calculating time difference and duration of the whole month.

```
long timeDiff = today.getTime() - firstDayOfMonth.getTime();
...
```

and then `predictValue = (currValue / timeDiff) * millisToMonth`

But this seems overly complicated. Is there a better, clean way to predict a value for the end of the month when current, value to date is given.

Answer (score 0):

If you do date operations constantly on your app, you could try the joda-time lib. Take a look at:
http://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html